# Algorithm to create a repeating increasing-then-decreasing number series

Tags: for-loop

I have been struggling for hours, does anybody know how to create an in line series of numbers that increases by one and upon hitting a maximum number, it decreases by one to a minimum value and repeats again. For example,

1 2 3 2 1 2 3 2 1 or

1 2 3 4 3 2 1 2 3 4 3 2 1.

To create this, use only one loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Assume max, min & count defined
for ( n=min, delta=1, i=0; i<count; i++ ) {
    Print n;
    If ( n==max )
        delta=-1;
    Else if ( n==min )
        delta=1;
    n+=delta;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop and check the product each step for max and min value then rotate the direction of the sub/add.

```
function alg(length, max) {
  var min = 1;
  var direction = 1;
  var product = 1;

  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (product >= max) { direction = -1; } 
    else if (product <= min) { direction = 1; }
    console.log(product);
    product += direction;
  }
}
```